# Process Builder only updates owner on contacts created after rule was activated?

Tags: account, process-builder

I have used process builder to create a process that updates the owner of contacts associated to an account when the account owner is changed.

The process works fine on new test accounts and contacts however when trying to test on accounts that existed in the sandbox prior to the activation of the rule nothing happens. The failure also applies when testing an old contact that I manually reassigned to a new account.

Any ideas what might be causing this and where I can start looking for a resoulution

[image: process as below]

[image: Criterea]

[image: Update]

Thank you

Comment: Did you select "**only when a record is created**" or"**when a record is created or edited**" when you set `Account` as the object in the first node in your process flow?

Comment: I'll toss in another possibility here. Did all of your accounts have these Record Types on them before you created your flow? Appears as though if they don't have one of these Record Types associated with the existing record, the owner isn't going to change for you.